# Difference with round keys and round constant in AES

Tags: aes, key-schedule

I am confused with round keys and round constant in AES. Are they the same? Can someone explain it to me?

Comment: Are you asking if the round keys are the same as the round constants, or if each round uses the same round key and round constant?

Comment: @forest I am asking if the round keys are the same as the round constants.

Comment: @jan The purpose of round constants is that they are constant bit streams that add just a little bit of noise to the key schedules.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Round keys are not the same as round constants. A round constant is *always* the same no matter what the key is. Round keys, however, are an expanded representation of the AES key being used.

For more information, read up on the [AES key schedule](https://www.samiam.org/key-schedule.html).